# Technical architecture diagram for an iPhone app

Tags: iphone

Is there any sample technical architecture diagram for an iPhone app which could depicts high level components and their interactions.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Is there something in particular you are looking for?  Have you taken a look at [Apple's](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) iOS application programming guides?  Or are you looking for their technology [overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898)?

Comment: I was looking for something similar to J2EE app wherein we show all the different components like EJB, JSP, Servlets, DB calls etc and their interconnections. In iPhone since we have MVC architecture and also I need to implement push notifications so I was looking for one technical architecture diagram which could depict all this. Please help.

Comment: And to be more specific, like i have a UI which will be controlled by UIViewController and a Model class to store the data. Similarly connection with Apple Push Notification Server.

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing like a web application architecture.

Sure, like any software, there's a "front end" and "a back end". But even the simplest web app requires a number of decisions to be made - consider a LAMP app - you've decided a linux box will run apache and serve HTTP responses based on PHP code accessing a MySQL database. And maybe on the client side you're using a Javascript framework!

But any popular web app is more complicated then that, because you need to make sure the app scales and runs all the time when there is a number of possible points of failure. Therefore, an architecture is necessary.

iOS is nothing like that. The user taps a piece of glass and their device draws something to the screen. The complexity of the architecture is based on the demands of the app - can the developer get away with using UIKit or do they need to use CoreAnimation/OpenGL? How complicated is the data in play, should they use Core Data? If it's a media-based app, what video/audio/image frameworks should be used, if any? Etc.

Possibly the only architecture decisions that need to be made are how an app interacts with a server backend... but that's a web app architecture, not an iOS app architecture. Typically an iOS developer that needs to diagram an app architecture can draw an arrow that points to "Cloud" and be done with it.

Comment: Your whole answer reads as you interpret "software architecture" as synonymous with "network architecture". That's a very narrow view and does not reflect the [common understanding of the term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_architecture).